# Image doesn't show on website. I downloaded the image and i used the local url

Tags: html

I wanted to show some png, but when I added the local URL to src, it didn't.

I used URL in Login.js

[image]

and here ise my img tag:

```
<img src='../../../logos/google.png'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two basic problems here.

## The base URL

A relative path needs to be computed **from** the base URL. In the case of the `src` attribute of an `<img>`, the base URL is the URL of the HTML document as displayed in the address bar of the browser. (This can be overridden with `<base>` but that is rarely done this decade).

It isn't clear what the URL of the page is here. The implication from your screenshot is that you are computing it from the file path of the source code of a Next.js page. That's *very* different to the URL that the browser gets.

## The final URL

The path also needs to be computed **to** the URL of the image. Again, you are working to a file path. The screenshot shows that the `logos` folder isn't even inside the `public` folder, so the image probably **doesn't have a URL at all**.

---

You need to:

- Give the image a URL
- Compute the relative path to that URL

If you are using Next.js (which is a supposition based on the folder structure; you haven't told us you are using that) then you might consider `import`ing the image instead (see [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-11#nextconfigjs-customization-to-import-images)) which would cause Next.js to generate a URL for the image and pass it back to the component automatically.