# Why is the .png file pathway not found in the HTML file?

Tags: html, image, file

I'm attempting to link an image in the form of a .png file in an HTML file for a QR card project. The file is local and I have tried multiple iterations of the pathway with no luck. No matter where I seem to save the file, the image will not appear on the web page!
[This is the .png and the file location info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzudT.png)

[image: screenshot of the html script]

Below is the  element in text format for further consideration
The result from this is the browser displays the "alt" description?
I really can't tell why this isn't working any help would be much appreciated!

```
<img src="MyFiles/QR_CARD/qr-code-component-main/images/image-qr-code.png" alt="DogWater">
```

Comment: Just move the image to your working directory

Comment: I'm fairly new so maybe I'm missing something super obvious but i can't move the .png file from my files into VScode? I tried creating a separate images folder. Maybe you could elaborate on your answer?

Comment: This question seemingly gets asked here and all over the internet every hour and the solution is always the same: your pathname is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407567/image-doesnt-show-on-website-i-downloaded-the-image-and-i-used-the-local-url

Answer (score 1):

The path to the image is resolved relative to the html file.

If your html file is

`MyFiles/QR_CARD/qr-code-component-main/index.html`

and your image is

`MyFiles/QR_CARD/qr-code-component-main/images/image-qr-code.png`

then the img src would be

`./images/image-qr-code.png`.

(This isn't 100% true for every scenario, but for the purposes of this conversation I think it's true.)

Comment: So after trying a number of other things, I've realized my problem is that I can't seem to add any image files to a folder at all in VS code? I create a new folder, and attempt to drag and drop the image files into them with no success? What am I missing? I know it's probably soooo stupid

Comment: Where are you dragging them from? Are they where you expect them to be on the file system (outside of vs code)? There are settings in vs code that hide some files from the explorer, so it’s _possible_ they’re there and just hidden from the view. This seems somewhat unlikely but it’s worth checking.